# How to detect missing XPATH and continue running for loop (Python)

Tags: for-loop, exception, xpath, python-requests

How can I detect a missing xpath and continue running the loop?

When I scrape text from a website

```
        url = "websiteurl" + partno
```

(i have found this url format to be consistent across products)

```
        response = requests.get(url)
        html_element = html.fromstring(response.text)
        try:  
            prodno = html_element.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/pes-product-main/section/div[2]/div/pes-main-area/pes-main-product-info//div/div/h2/text()')

            if str(prodno) != ("['" + partno + "']"): # need [' '] because when the string is pulled from the dataframe, it will have those and flag the comparison as wrong.
                print(prodno, partno)
                prodscrapefailure.append(prodno)

            elif str(prodno) == ("['" + partno + "']"): 
                print('yay')
                productno.append(prodno)

        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
```

I have a list of part numbers to scrape:
110XCA20300,
140ACI03000,
140ACI04000,
140ACO02000,
cheesecake,
140ARI03010,
140ATI03000,
140CPS11420,
140CPS11420C,
140CPS12420

My aim is to scrape all the pages loaded using requests_html, 'cheesecake' is a stand in for an incorrect product code. I am trying to recognise when an xpath cant be found as the error page is loaded instead and have it write the incorrect product code to a data frame and then continue with the rest of the product codes.

I have been trying to use exception but keep meeting the error code "
ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 0 columns"

How can I detect a missing xpath and continue running the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that in this instance I could just add the input 'partno' to the prodscrapefailure list. instead of trying prodno, which of course, didn't exist in the case that nothing was found.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).